# How to drop a bucket in hive?

Tags: hive

There are huge data in our sys. We can't afford the storage so we want to remove the usless data.

We are using the data as the partition for the hive table and we are going to remove the data by the partition whe the data is usless.

Currently we want to remove more data by the buckets in the hive.

Any one know how to do that ??

Comment: i am confused - drop bucket or drop partition? Drop partition is easier. Drop bucket i am not sure if its possible - you can try dropping the bucket folder.

Comment: Hive table Bucket is a file inside table or partition directory. Try to drop file.

Comment: @KoushikRoy   you mean that drop the file directly in hdfs?

Comment: Pretty much yes, but as i said hive manages them internally so you need superuser to drop it. And i suggest pls do it in Dev/Sandbox.